# Using xgettext to extract translatable strings from VueJS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gettext, xgettext

I am trying to use `xgettext` to extract strings to be translated from a VueJS file. I am not able to get `xgettext` to recognize JS that is in a VueJS computed property though.

For example, I have an element in my `<template>` like so:

`<input :placeholder="translator.gettext('Phone')" />`

This fails to get picked up when running `xgettext` like so:

`xgettext --from-code=UTF-8 --language=JavaScript`

But if I have a translatable string as a function call, it is picked up. For example:

```
<div>{{ translator.gettext('This is picked up 1') }}</div>
<input :placeholder="translator.gettext('This is NOT picked up')" />
<div>{{ translator.gettext('This is picked up 2') }}</div>
```

The `input` placeholder is not picked up, but the other 2 strings are.

I believe this is because `xgettext` considers anything inside an html property to be just a string, but VueJS will run any value in a property prefixed by a `:` as pure JavaScript.

Is there any way to get `xgettext` to understand that this code is JS and not just a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think translation does not work on attributes. Maybe you can try using a computed property to achieve this like:

```
computed: {
   placeholderText () {
     return this.translator.gettext('This is a text')
   },
},
```

and then use this computed property in your template like:

```
<input :placeholder="placeholderText" />
```

Or, you can create a filter for this like:

```
Vue.filter('translate', value => {
  return !value ? '' : Vue.prototype.translator.gettext(value.toString())
})
```

and then use it like:

```
<input :placeholder="'This is a text' | translate" />
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now as a workaround, but this isn't optimum. The problem is that every contributor needs to remember this, and its easy to end up with a un-translated string without knowing it

Comment: I see. Maybe you can create a filter for this and use it wherever needed, that way contributors will not have to create a computed property for every text they need.

Comment: The filter seems like the best option if there is no current gettext option. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, thanks!